# How to add a slot to processing queue using a ring buffer with three pointers?

Tags: game-mechanics, data-structure, c

I am working on a farm game made in C. I am currently working on adding item processing, such as milling wheat into flour. Under the hood, I am using a ring buffer to handle the queues for processing. I keep 3 pointers for the ring buffer. A collect pointer for the rear, a new task pointer for the front, and an active pointer to point to the currently active event.

Right now I am working on adding a mini upgrade, a new slot for a queue of the processing building. I am having problems with deciding how to handle this in a way that is good for me the programmer and the eventual user.

When I add a new slot to a queue, it changes how my 3 pointers should be positioned. For example, if the queue was full, the new task pointer should now be at the new empty slot. There is also the active pointer. If you have 3 slots in the queue, events in slots 1 and 2, and you add another event such that it gets added to slot 0. Then you add a new slot to the queue such that it is slot 3. The active pointer would get stuck in slot 3, resulting in behavior that is not wanted.

I currently see 3 options:

1. Do not allow the addition of new slots

   - This is likely the simplest solution, however, it is not quite what I want.
2. Only allow the addition of new slots when the entire queue is empty.

   - This would work well and is what I am currently leaning toward. This is good for the programmer, but I don't think it is convenient for the user. Would this be a good trade-off in convenience for the programmer vs convenience for the user? Would this be considered a sane game mechanic?
3. Manually place the pointers into the correct places.

   - This would be the best in convenience for the user, however, it would be a lot of work for the programmer.

Which would be the best approach? Is there another solution that I am missing?

Comment: when you are asking yourself these kinds of questions, the answer is to always look at games of the same type that are succesfull and see what mods users created for those games.... the most used mods are usually there to improve quality of life for the user if the game lacks into that... or new content or new graphics and so on... mods are there to fix something

Comment: also the idea of @garbaj "i'll fix this later" works wonderfully... better to make something else that you know you can do easily and add a bunch of easy features than focus entirely on fixing one single feature that takes a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should sacrifice usability for programming convenience. A queue that can enlarge is not the halting problem, so we can just bite the bullet and solve it.

Presumably you have a maximum number of queue slot upgrades? If so, you can make the queue the largest size it could ever be right from the start, and store the current capacity in a byte nearby. When something wants to add something to the queue, check the current capacity and deny the option if the queue is full. Then upgrading is just incrementing this value, and no pointers need to move because they're still valid in the new state as well.